# Google Identity Platform: Cannot exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens

Tags: ios, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

I'm trying to get access to Google Drive API and I read [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp).
My iOS app sends first request to ask for permission to endpoint https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth.

User grants permission. I get a code. Next step is to authorization code for refresh and access tokens.

As for installed apps, I don't need to send client secret.
In order to do that iOS app sends POST request to the endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

with headers:

```
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

body:

```
code={CODE_FROM_OAUTH_SERVER}&client_id={CLIENT_ID_FROM_CONSOLE}&redirect_uri={APP_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}:/code&grant_type=authorization_code
```

I get the response:

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

App is registered in Google console.

My question is am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which type of credentials did you create on developer console?

Comment: @DaImTo, credentials for installed apps, in my case - Create client ID -> iOS

Comment: and you followed https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/?

Comment: @DaImTo, the whole point of this question - I don't want use libraries, if I would like to, I can simply use Firebase/Auth and it will do what I want, I want full understanding of what is happening

Answer (score 3):

It is sending the specified data in a **POST** request to the HTTP server, same as when browser do when we fill a HTML form and do submit . This will cause to pass the data to the server using the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You should try by changing the way you pass the OAuth parameters like `client_id`, ,`redirect_uri`, `grant_type`, etc.

Or should try making Native client of default type.

Comment: I tried different ways and it didn't work, maybe you have concrete suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible source of parsing errors is the `redirect_uri` . It should be url-encoded.

Comment: Yes, I have added URL encoding, it didn't help